# Trying to change label location dependent on what button text is equal to? won't work

Tags: java, swing

My program doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to change the label location dependent on what the text is equal to, but I seem to need to press the button twice for this to be achieved. What have I done wrong?

Code:

```
private void TvShow1ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Showname.setText("TvShow1"); 
    textmove();
}  

private void TvShow2ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Showname.setText("TvShow2"); 
    textmove();
}  

public void textmove (){
    if(Showname.getText().toString().equals("TvShow1") || Showname.getText().toString().equals("TvShow2")){
        Showname.setLocation(-10, 10);
    } 
    else {
       Showname.setLocation(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first set the frame layout to null

```
frame.setlayout(null);
```

then use setBounds() method to set the location of the label

```
label.setBounds(10,10,150,30); // x , y , height and width
```

then on the button is clicked do this in the actionperformed method

```
label.setBounds(10,30,150,30);
validate();
```

i try this and worked with me :)

[image]

Comment: That may work. But as I'm using netbeans .setlayout(null)
messes up the page